# Row isn't taking the full width anymore in WP Bakery Visual Composer page builder

Tags: wordpress

I'm taking a single image module in a row with column. But when I've try to put it as a full width image then it takes some padding to left and right side. I've taken the page as a full width no sidebar stretch page as well. But still the problem showing up.

What's wrong ??

Answer (score -1):

In my Idea instead of taking your time to solve a WP Bakery problem if you know well a about CSS use your own CSS in customization > extra CSS. but if you want to solve and understand the problem, check these steps I have mention below.

1. check WP Bakery element padding and margin. may be the element has some padding or margin in the WP Bakery setting.
2. check if you don't use any extra CSS that make conflict with your WP Bakery element.

The Last thing that is important and may your final solution is:

3. in your browser press F12 to see inspect and find the class or any CSS selector that have effect on element. in these scenario you can find the problem. if WP Bakery class's have effect you can use step one to find wich part of WP Bakery should change. and if you find other css you can solve it by just find the class or id or any css selector that has effect on your code.

Comment: I've tried so many ways as well. But still facing this problem.

Comment: I'm working with page builder instead of code. So that how can I show my code ??

Comment: this page builder has effect on your code and so that why you can not get your willing result. you should see how its work on your code as I explained to you.

Comment: Okay. Still working on the way to find out the conflict design from my code. Regards.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your help.